# How to fix "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" in Battleships game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a homework assignment where the player places down 5 ships in a 1D list and the computer guesses them. However, a line of code `if board[guess]=="X":` isn't working, even though it worked in my one-player version.

Also, I don't think the for i in range etc etc part is actually making 5 ships and assigning them to the list.

```
from random import randint
import random
board=["O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O"]

scounter=0
counter=0
shipcount=0

for i in range(5):
     place=int(input("Input index to place ship!"))
     ship=board.insert(place,"X")
     shipcount-=1

while scounter<6:
     guess=(random.choice(board))
     print(guess)
     if board[guess]=="X":
          print("Uh oh!",5-scounter,"ships left")
          scounter+=1
          counter+=1
     else:
          print("Yay, it missed!")
          counter+=1

print("The computer sunk your ships in",counter,"tries!")
```

RESULTS:

```
Input index to place ship!1
Input index to place ship!2
Input index to place ship!3
Input index to place ship!4
Input index to place ship!5
X
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//Desktop/CODE/battleships 3.py", line 17, in <module>
    if board[guess]=="X":
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.choice` returns a random element from `board` (which is a list strings), so `guess` is a string.

instead of `if board[guess]=="X":` you can use `if guess=="X":`

notice: you can hit the same ship multiple times :P, and other several logical bugs as well (try printing `board` at the end of the input loop, see that it is not exactly what you expected...).

but this is out of scope for this question...